# Can you help me convert what appears to be a json value to a comma delimited value?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Looking for some help.  Not really familiar with json, especially when they are recursive.

I am working with a WordPress plugin to export the WooCommerce database, including variable product image galleries.  I managed to make the export feature work, but need some help with the import.  The plugin currently imports what appears to be a json field into the column in question, but I need it to be comma delimited.

I have access to the snippet which calls a lot of wp functions and ultimately creates the string below.  I can take that final return and convert it into a comma delimited value but don't know how.  All of my json_decode($json) attempts have returned null.

How do I convert:

```
a:2:{i:0;i:45119;i:1;i:45120;}
```

to

```
45119,45120
```

in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a [serialized string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You just need to [unserialize it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!  Was completely unfamiliar.  With your help, I figured it out in seconds.  Please submit this as an answer and I will mark it as such.